# QScrollArea только вертикальный скролл

Tags: qt, gui

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы QScrollArea работала только по вертикали? То есть при вставке дополнительных виджетов по вертикали появлялась бы полоса прокрутки, а при добавлении их по горизонтали QScrollArea расширялась, либо же если она задана фиксированной, то сжимала то, что находится внутри нее?